# Failed to suspend

Tags: laptop

when I close the laptop lid and then open it after sometime, I see the message on my screen saying "Failed to suspend".
What is the problem while the laptop is trying to suspend.

Comment: Can you tell us what graphics card you are running? Or what model your laptop is? There are a great many things that could cause this and having that information would help us narrow it down.

Comment: sorry, forgot to answer the solution. its resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the problem by installing acpi-support from the ubuntu software centre. Here is the thread that helped me http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1608752

This was the cause of problem
[Hibernate and Suspend do not exist anymore, help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10273/hibernate-and-suspend-do-not-exist-anymore-help)