# Hibernate and Suspend do not exist anymore, help

Tags: hibernate, suspend

When I close the lid of my laptop and open it after some time I am greeted with a message "Failed to suspend".
When I tried to manually suspend/hibernate, I saw these options are not available there at all. Of course, they did exist when I did the fresh installation but I can't see them anymore.

I am totally pissed off with this. Please help.

Comment: Are you using Wubi? Wubut doesn't fully support suspend/hibernate.

Comment: No I use ubuntu as a sole operating system on my laptop.

Comment: That was supposed to be Wubi, Wubut.

Comment: wubut? I meant, I only use Ubuntu, so no wubi.

Comment: Can you provide any more detail of what model of laptop or what hardware you have. That will help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: question should be closed now, it's solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the problem by installing acpi-support from the ubuntu software centre. Here is the thread that helped me http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1608752

Answer (score 0):

I know you've solved this, but I want to mark it as answered in the system:

Installing acpi-support can bring the suspend/resume back, sometimes issues are fixed in kernel updates and sometimes (rarely) issues are fixed in a bios upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Had kind of same issues with my toshiba satellite. After wondering around for long time I ended up installing the new kernel 2.6.36 from here, http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.36-maverick/

It seems to have resolved the issues at least when I am suspending from command line sudo pm-suspend. If I close the lid still haven't figured it out why its not working.